# PHP check if user viewed specific page

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently building web app in PHP where the client wants to have logged in users. There will be hierarchy so the new users won't have priviliges as higher positioned users. The priviliged users will be able to post articles and files for users to see.

This is my question: How can adminisitrator or the privileged user check who viewed the article or downloaded the files. Is this possible via PHP?

Comment: Well you could have the pages track when logged in users load them, and same with the downloads.

Comment: Expecting somebody to say "What have you tried" as it has been now on SO. Hard for new comers to learn something as we did previously and learned a lot !!

Comment: @Sarfraz: Of course, just like when somebody asks "guys, my faucet broke and water is spilling all over my place, I was wondering if it would be possible to somehow fix the faucet, or I should just get used to having water everywhere"

Comment: I personally don't much care for the "What have you tried" comments. Just my *personal* opinion.

Comment: @JonathanSampson: I dont either :)

Comment: haven't tried anything yet, just gathering ideas so I can make a plan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible, but you won't get it out of the box most likely. You'll need to store the access history for any given user server-side. You could do this by simply storing user ids, urls, and times in a seperate table in your database. Something along the lines of:

```
 5 | '/filedownload.php?file=cake-instructions.php' | 2012-02-15 08:23:11
 8 | '/company-information'                         | 2012-02-15 08:15:01
```

Anytime a user accesses a url, you store their id, that url, and the current time in a database. This would then be readily accessible to administrators if they want to perform queries to see who viewed what, and when.

Comment: thanks for the answer, is there a way where i could you database? possibly create a special table just for viewing specific articles and there I could store somehow who viewed it and who did not.. could be wrong thinking but i dont have a clue how to start

Comment: @Vojtech I meant to suggest doing this in a database - I apologize for not stating that more clearly.

Comment: and this info would be stored after the user viewed the article and then i could use a mysql query which could select users who did and who did not viewed the article based on their user_id, correct?

Comment: I am going to try article_id instead of the address, just to make it more simple .. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table named `Article`, you can store a variable in that table, lets say `nr_of_views`. Each time a user views an article/page, take the id of the article and increment the `nr_of_views` variable. Something like that.